# Style inconsistencies in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I may be laboring under a misunderstanding here. When I apply a style in MS word, and then I change that style, I am used to every instance of that style being changed.

However, I have word documents where a given style appears differently in the same document? How can I undo and prevent that. For instance, I have a document where quotations appear one way in one part, and a different way elsewhere. If I click in the area of the first quotation and select modify on the quotation style, it matches the quotation style there.

If I move to the other quotation and click modify on the quotation style, again I see that the style there matches what I see.

But I'm not clear on how a style is showing up two different ways in the same document, and how I can change that and unify them. I don't want two styles of "quotation", or of "normal" etc....

Answer (score 1):

The trick to getting this right is to stop using the formatting controls and start using **only** styles. Use the formatting controls only when you are creating a new style or editing a style. Also, for the sake of productivity, it is better to just type out your content and only work with the styles at the end; all at once. It'll save you a lot of time in the end because you'll know that you did them all the same.

BTW, if these documents might ever need to be converted to HTML it is especially important to get this right. Inline styles are handled ridiculously bad in Word.